# Lamar causes 500.30 error when using ServiceRegistry

Tags: .net, .net-core, lamar

I am using Lamar as the DI for .Net Core (2.2) Web API.

Program.cs

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseLamar()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

When I have following code at Startup.cs the program starts fine.

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        { }
```

As soon as I change the method to this

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(ServiceRegistry services)
        { }
```

Starting the Web API will show

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

In Event Viewer there are couple of Errors.

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\xxx\path\to\Web.API\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.
```

and

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\xxx\path\to\Web.API\' failed to load clr and managed application. CLR worker thread exited prematurely
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused because I just replaced *ConfigureServices* call with the ServiceRegistry. I should actually use *ConfigureContainer*:

```cs
        public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services)
        { }
```